# wordpress inherited from a developer and now unable to login

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress work which i got from previous developer and they dumped the project, now whenever i try to go and try to get login into the website, it goes this way

```
www.website.com/wp-login.php
```

it redirects to `www.website.com/not_found` with the following error on page

```
Warning: require(/home2/website/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/website/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home2/website/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home2/website/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65
```

my htaccess file is linked

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6i7PS8ah)

Looks like problem is here but not sure how i can fix it

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)website.com/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)website.com/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)website.com/cviiz-giris
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)website.com/cviiz-yonet
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)website.com/cviiz-kayit
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^vdotwwiq6u0zu411l3y6b
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=register
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=postpass
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]
```

Comment: I would just remove this rule and see, if the login works again. There might be more problems though, unless the /not_found contains exactly this error message.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. like Olaf said. Remove all the rules from htaccess and see if you can login

Answer (score 0):

download http://wordpress.org/latest.zip then unzip. Copy the wp-includes/functions.php to wp-includes inside your website.

Remove the .htaccess then try to login. If you use custom permalinks, then going to Permalinks then click Save button.

Comment: afterdoing what you said, gettingthis error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_installing() in /home2/website/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1363`

Comment: It seem another files are deleted. Please delete wp-admin and wp-includes folder. Then upload the new one